# High voltage non-inverting operational amplifier for DC signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, power-electronics, electrical, single-supply-op-amp

I am currently using LT6090 with Vcc=140 and Vee=0 for DC signal amplification with gain of 31 in non-inverting mode. For an input signal of 0-4V from a DAC the output measured is 0-124V (step change is <20mV, calculated as per DAC resolution).

What I am trying to achieve is by using the same opamp above I want the output range from 100V to 224V with Vcc=240 and Vee=100 such that Vcc-Vee=140 as per the datasheet spec.
But the issue is now the input should be above Vee(100V).
How can I achieve the same step change for 100 to 240V range using 0-4V DAC range?

Comment: Depending on context, wouldn't an isolated 100V supply with its 0V connected to the current output be simplest? Or a fixed -100V rail below the current 0V? (If you can isolate the load) Neither involves changing the existing amplifier.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, yes this is a viable solution and will work. But is it possible to have two such  (from 2 separate opamps) programmable output from 100 to 240V with a single isolated supply(-100V with isolated ref) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way of shifting the input signal to the new ground level. The easiest way is to use an isolation amplifier. How practical that is depends on any accuracy and cost constraints you may have and whether you can produce a supply rail relative to the Vee (you could always use an isolated DC-DC converter. There are probably commercial modules that will do this all in one.

Alternatively you could make an analog level shifter by building a current sink that produces a current proportional to the 0-4V signal, and then receiving that at the other end. The LT6090 does not have an input common-mode range that extends down to the negative rail so it might make sense to create a pseudo signal ground at Vee+4V or so, and then you just need a resistor (for safety) to the current sink collector or drain and a feedback resistor (just build a simple inverting transimpedance amplifier). For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzuZ7l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As shown this will yield a nominal output of 105V to 240V for input 0-3.86V.

Comment: I'd probably want to work out a means of getting a global NFB wrapped around that. That would probably involve a divider of some kind and another opamp to feed backwards to the control opamp stage. I feel uncomfortable with feedback localized to OA3.

Comment: @jonk why? I don't see anything wrong with it, making assumptions about accuracy, of course. Global feedback is going to have compensation challenges. This will just work.

Comment: Just inside my gut, right now. I have a mental diagram of what's bothering me, but it's a "picture" and I'd need to write an answer to make it clearer. I believe I recall reading similar thoughts from Winfield Hill, back in the day. I wish I could remember exactly where, right now. Maybe I should just draw up what I'm thinking about. But it breaks down into four parts: The control amp stage, followed by the level shifter stage, followed by the HV output stage, with feedback via some 1:N divider back via another opamp to the originating control opamp stage. If that's no help, let's drop it.

Comment: @jonk Win has a +/-500V amplifier design 4x.137 but that's way more than OP  is asking for. It needs global fb because the output stage is discrete MOSFETs. About 40 or 50 components.

Comment: That sounds way more complex than I was thinking. Is that book out, yet??? Oh, and since you must have it, what does it say??? Global NFB? Or? (Hmm. I see Amazon says it is out: January 30, 2020!)

Comment: @jonk Yes, it's out. 20% discount from the publisher Cambridge until end Feb, or Amazon is about the same price in the USA (~10% discount but free ship). Code AEX2019P at Cambridge checkout. He used global FB but he had to because the output stage is a bunch of drifty discrete transistors, not a precise HV op-amp.

Comment: I started by thinking about the output stage as discrete. (You, obviously, just used the same opamp the OP was using.) So I suppose that's my problem, then. Thanks for the notes about the book. I'll be buying it. (I was wondering if it would ever reach the shelves. Glad to hear it has.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Works as intended.

Comment: As a note for anyone else who might be interested, the 'book' is the X-chapters addendum to the 3rd edition of Hill & Horowitz Art of Electronics.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, Thanks for the information. Just ordered the X-chapters from Amazon!